# Play framework app stops working when server exited

Tags: playframework, server, sbt, ubuntu-14.04, sbt-native-packager

I have a Play framework web application that works when deployed to my ubuntu (14.04) server following the below steps:

- ran 'dist' in sbt
- transferred resulting .zip file to server
- ssh'd
  into server and ran the app using "/bin/
  -Dplay.crypto.secret=abcxyz"

This runs the application in the foreground fine but kills it immediately when I lose internet connection (breaking the ssh connection to the server).

I need my application to be up and running continuously (until I decide to stop it) from the point I run it and I would like it to run in the background (daemon).

Will running the app as a daemon service on the server prevent the app from stopping when I exit the server through terminal? If so, how do I go about doing this? Is there a simple way to make sure the application runs regardless of me logging out of the server it's running on/losing connection to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to do that. Here is a quick way with `nohup`:

```
nohup ./bin/$NAME -Dplay.crypto.secret=abcxyz -Dpidfile.path=/dev/null > /dev/null 2>&1 &
```

I usually send the pid file to `/dev/null` so I don't have lock problems when play restarts. Note that, since this will run a background process, you should configure a file logger to see the server output.

Answer (score 1):

The playframework enables the [JavaServerAppPlugin](http://sbt-native-packager.readthedocs.io/en/stable/archetypes/java_server/index.html) from sbt-native-packager, which provides [systemloaders](http://sbt-native-packager.readthedocs.io/en/stable/archetypes/java_server/customize.html#service-manager-configuration) managing your application lifecycle. However you need to build a **debian** file to use this feature.

1. Build you app with `sbt debian:packageBin`
2. Copy the resulting debian file to your server
3. Install with `sudo dpkg -i your-app.deb`

### Configuration

@nnmat is right you should add `-Dpidfile.path=/dev/null`. You can do that in your `build.sbt` ( [see the documentation](http://sbt-native-packager.readthedocs.io/en/stable/archetypes/java_app/customize.html#via-build-sbt) )

```
javaOptions in Universal ++= Seq("-Dpidfile.path=/dev/null")
```

Also make sure you [configure the correct systemloader](http://sbt-native-packager.readthedocs.io/en/stable/archetypes/java_server/customize.html#service-manager-configuration). By default it's `Upstart` for debian packages. You might want to use `Systemd`.
If you use sbt-native-packager `1.2.x` take a look at the latest documentation.

cheers,
Muki

Comment: Thanks @Muki :) I'm using nmat's solution just at the moment to get up and running, I will definitely look into implementing this solution later on though!

Comment: It should actually be easier using a debian file. You won't have to manually kill the running instances on each deploy. This is what a systemloader is good for ;) Saves you a lot of manual work.